# scala anorm and mysql

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

I wanna read all the records of the table by using mysql stored procedure with scala play2 anorm.

**The procedure below:-**

```
create or replace procedure readAllUsers(p_cur sys_refcursor) as
begin
   open p_cur for select * from users;
end;
```

your kind help is much appreciatable.

Answer (score 1):

Using raw sql commands you can call stored procedures within anorm.
Straight from the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAnorm) examples:

```
SQL("EXEC readAllUsers").execute()
```

Comment: @AsaithambiR the snippet in my answer is anorm code to execute a stored procedure. What exactly are you missing here?

Comment: my need is to get the resultset from the mysql stored procedure which is having the refcursor as output parameter.

Comment: Is any possible to read the output parameter of stored procedure by using anorm.

Comment: For Anorm, there is no difference whether the statement is a `SELECT ...` or a `EXEC proc`, as soon as the result is a set of rows (not an update). Then you're back to the basics of Anorm, and the [documentation of how to parse result](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm) is the most appropriate answer.